# feature request: LMSOTFY

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

**Do we need to keep down voting the question after I've already accepted the fact it's a bad idea?**

Can we add a feature like lmgtfy/lmddgtfy to SO? I could use this on other websites to point to a SO search for that question.

I think it would be pretty neat anyway. Thoughts?

Comment: I had to google lmgtfy to figure out what the question was about!

Comment: Somebody already registered that domain back in July.  How long you been thinking about this?

Comment: @will 3 hours ago.

Comment: *@User* Yes, because we're a vengeful and petty lot.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One of the reasons that LMGTFY is banned on SE sites is that it's... well, pretty rude. No matter what you're trying to say with a LMGTFY, you can say it more politely and helpfully another way. Doing this on another site to point to SO is no less rude.

Comment: +1. I was going to upvote 40 minutes ago when you posted this answer, but your new gravatar sent me into a trance.

Comment: @Andy, [blame Chacha](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/201286#201286). Actually, it's an optical illusion; the "blue" and "green" are the same color. See my profile for explanatory link, if you have five minutes.

Comment: very clever :-)